# What features are missing from Python IDE tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, development-environment

What are the most desired features currently lacking in any Python IDE tools?

I'm also interested in what's missing in Komodo 6 but available in other tools (I currently use Komodo 6 for Python 3 under Windows).

[I am asking for this to be made community wiki if appropriate.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a [small review](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/is-there-a-better-python-ide/) of editors/IDE's recently, and the most common thing missing IMO is some sort of project management, integrated debugging and ways to set up custom python paths per project.

When it comes to Komodo, as far as my quick test could ascertain, the project management in Komodo was quite basic, but it does have integrated debugging. Also the code completion drove me nuts.

Personally I use WingIDE, and I'm not missing any features at all, really. Especially I love how you can set a main file, which it will analyze and see that if the main file modified sys.path, it will analyze that path so you can do code completion and click-to-definition on those packages too. That's really nice when you use zc.buildout, for example, and a feature I looked for in other IDE's when I tested it, and didn't find many that supported it.

PyCharm, the new kid on the block, has refactoring support which looks interesting, but I don't know if it really works and how useful it is in practice.

Comment: +1 for integrated debugging.  If anyone can point me at a Python IDE with a real debugger, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: All of the above fit that description, AFAIK.

Comment: +1 for Wing. I can't imagine doing real application development in Python without it. The Debug Probe alone is worth the rather minimal cost.